# iOS facebook SDK 3 > Get the signed request

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I try to get the signed request to login the user via a webservice but I only have access to the accessToken on FBSession.

I saw this link 
[Facebook Signed Request for iOS (HMAC SHA256)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812140/facebook-signed-request-for-ios-hmac-sha256)
who shows how to convert the signed_request but doesn't show how to get it.

Need help :)

Comment: You only get a `signed_request` when a) you have an actual web app that runs inside facebook.com as a canvas/page tab app, or b) you use the client-side login with the JS SDK.

Comment: BTW, that link you posted DOES show how to get the signed request. Actually, you CREATE it yourself it's not given to you (as per the posting). You Base64 the payload and you HMAC SHA256 the secret. Then you append them together separated with a period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undersand you right you want your app to login and then make a call to a server where you need to check the users credential again.
I used [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) tutorial for the authentication.
Then when I call the server I send the accessToken property as a parameter to check the users credentials on the server. You can get the token value like this:

```
FBSession.activeSession.accessToken
```

On the server side you can then set the access token to the value you got from the app.

Comment: I see, so this is impossible to get this like with the JS SDK.
Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a gist that generates a signed request which you can then use to authenticate a user on your server without having to query the graph API.

You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/3962188

You can find the original question I compiled it for here: [Facebook iOS SDK to return a signed request object upon login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874091/facebook-ios-sdk-to-return-a-signed-request-object-upon-login)

Please note that most of the code is simply a compilation of existing open source code, but I haven't seen any fully working implementation like this anywhere.